# How would I get the JQuery function to work being called in HTML for AWS S3 static page?

Tags: jquery, forms, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to create form for AWS S3 static sight using JQuery Script and the form/function doesn't work. I've tried to change the html form to `onClick="submitToAPI(this)` instead of using `(event)`.

The form code:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
      <h4>Name:</h4>
      <input type="text" style="height:35px;" id="name-input" placeholder="Enter name here…" class="form-control" style="width:100%;" /><br/>
      <h4>Phone:</h4>
      <input type="phone" style="height:35px;" id="phone-input" placeholder="Enter phone number" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"/><br/>
      <h4>Email:</h4>
      <input type="email" style="height:35px;" id="email-input" placeholder="Enter email here…" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"/><br/>
      <h4>How can we help you?</h4>
      <textarea id="description-input" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message…" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></textarea><br/>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc7cVMUAAAAAM1yxf64wrmO8gvi8A1oQ_ead1ys" class="form-control" style="width:100%;"></div>
      <button type="button" onClick="submitToAPI(event)" class="btn btn-lg" style="margin-top:20px;">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, within script tags, I have this code for the JQuery that Sends the responses to an API that directs it into an email.

```
function submitToAPI(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var URL = "_URL TO API_";

       var name = $("#name-input").val();
       var phone = $("#phone-input").val();
       var email = $("#email-input").val();
       var desc = $("#description-input").val();
       var data = {
          name : name,
          phone : phone,
          email : email,
          desc : desc
        };

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url : "_URL TO API_",
         dataType: "json",
         crossDomain: "true",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: JSON.stringify(data),


         success: function () {
           // clear form and show a success message
           alert("Successfull");
           document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
       location.reload();
         },
         error: function () {
           // show an error message
           alert("UnSuccessfull");
         }});
     }
```

Since I haven't used JQuery before and this is the first time I'm trying to get an actual website up, is there something I missing within the function/onClicked that would keep this from running and submitting the form?

Comment: Have you tried making the js file public readable in your s3 bucket?

Comment: @pkarfs I haven't set up the bucket yet. I'm uses Brackets and testing through the live feature. Even in that case, I don't have the JQ in a separate file, it's scripted already in the HTML.

Comment: ah I have a similar setup using brackets live where i am fetching data from an s3 bucket fronted by apigateway with a .js script. have you tried debugging your site / using console logs to check where your script is being triggered?

Comment: @pkarfs I checked and got this: index.html:350 Uncaught ReferenceError: submitToAPI is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. On the line when I called the function in the button tag.

Comment: Figured out I had to set up a separate script tag importing the Jquery documentation. Then found out that I somehow have a CORS problem. "Access to XMLHttpRequest at '_API GATEWAY URL_' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: yes correct you will need to enable cors as you are trying to access api-gateway from a localhost

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to change the “Access-Control-Allow-Attribute” when creating CORD to ‘*’ to include all possible points. I had to this because of running tests in a local host.